How are part-time studies viewed in the English-speaking countries?
In our department, we recently discussed about part-time studies in combination with occupational work. Hereby, I mean degrees where lectures take place during the evening / the weekend and where most participants / "students" already have a full degree. The discussion included full professors, post-docs and some individuals working in the industries.
During the discussion I realized that the perception of part-time studies varies widely. In fact, some people claimed that "one simply buys a degree". One professor said that candidates who undertook a part-time degree are highly interesting to him, since they manage work and studies at the same time. Further to that, said person claimed that the grades are not important to him, since it is more about completing the degree. I know this might be very country specific so I would like to ask the following question: How are part-time degrees evaluated in the English-speaking countries, such as the United States / the United Kingdom? I am specifically interested in the graduate level.
Thank you very much!

I was very fortunate, eons ago, to have both the opportunity to do a night-school masters and a supportive employer. This allowed me to bootstrap my professional situation for my own benefit and that of my young family. At a later date the stars aligned for my PhD work. Maybe there were those who thought less of someone like me on a nontraditional path, but the folks I worked with seemed to understand and appreciate it.

There is no inherent reason that part-time programs catering to employed professionals should have lower quality.  Many high-end universities offer courses with contact hours outside of normal work hours and these are high-quality courses that are comparable to standard courses in the institution.  Having said this, in some institutions there is financial pressure for the university to run a program that successfully attracts enough students to make it financially viable/beneficial to the institution, and in such cases (particularly for less prestigious universities) there may be some internal pressure to ensure that the courses are not too taxing on the students.
This means that there is some nuance and judgment involved in assessing the likely quality of part-time programs provided to full-time professionals.  Academics are generally okay with this in principle, but may be skeptical of the quality of programs in particular cases where there are "red flags".  If you wish to avoid potential negative inferences about the quality of your program, it might be best to look for established programs that have run successfully for long enough that they have an established reputation, or programs from high-prestige universities where it is less likely that course quality will be watered down in order to attract/retain busy students.

There Is Some Nuance
There's nothing generally wrong with the idea of pursuing a degree, part time, while working, from a university that is catering to professionals or otherwise non-traditional students with full schedules during the day.
One of my master's degrees (computer science) is exactly that.
I got it in the mid 00's, which was just about the time that remote learning was becoming a possibility, and that institution was an early investor in those technologies.  The tech couldn't quite do real-time streaming, but lectures with very high fidelity whiteboard captures would be made available no later than 12 hours after they were recorded in front of live students.  We were expected to show up in person for exams, had access to office hours and e-mail discussions with the professors, submitted homework, etc.  And the university was accredited, and an R2 institute.
That was as much as the tech of the day could minimize the gap between remote and in-person.  Even today, you couldn't do too much better except to add live-streaming, and replace e-mail with video chats.
So that's great, and no one should be knocking an experience like that without cause.  If people are showing up for live lectures, they shouldn't be knocked for that, either.
But here's the nuance:  It was about the same time that the University of Phoenix started blitzing the market with their own on-line long distance programs.  UoPX was (still is?) widely regarded as a diploma mill.
It is not trivially easy to distinguish between those two ends of the spectrum, so skepticism may not be completely unwarranted.   The farther you get from the remote-but-not-second-class model that I took part in, the lower the quality of the education is likely to be, and the more that skepticism will apply.
My experiences are approaching twenty years ago, and anecdotal aside from that, so I don't have a great list of do's and don'ts, here.  But I can offer two broad ideas for quality checking:

If the non-traditional curriculum is attached to a quality university, that's a good sign, subject to common sense; I don't know what Harvard offers, say, but it's unlikely to get you the fabled networking opportunities if you never meet people on a daily basis for several years.

If you work for a company that supports continuing education for their employees (my employer paid the whole thing for me) the relevant HR staffer should be able to steer you in the right direction.



I am one of these students and have been for about 15 years.  I got my teaching degree paid for by my employer (an R2), and I am currently working on two masters degrees at the night school at an R1.  These degrees are also significantly discounted because I am a staff member.  The average master's degree at my R1 will cost me less than $500 + a few fees.  In all three cases, I was looking for experience in my job or upskilling in some way.  I have also taken classes that were of interest to me and more of like a hobby (these were with the normal grad programs at the R1 and thus cost me more, like about $600/each).
The night school classes are hard.  I have taken both "regular" classes and "night" classes at the same school, and the night classes are often harder in my experience.  This is a difficult comparison because the same subject areas are not offered in both schools.  However, the focus of the night school classes are often more vocational and focus on upskilling more than theoretical information. In my case, this means instead of reflection and research papers, which I am used to and pretty skilled at, I have to make projects with my new skills (which I am less good at right now).  I may have to work about 60 hours a week and then also do at least 10 hours of school work each week.  It's a long week.  I sometimes have to make hard choices, getting a B+ can be a strategic choice for me if my workload at my job is too intense and an A is out of reach.  My job comes first.
In terms of how people view folks like me, yes there is a bias that some people have.  This came up with a Harvard Law Professor last year during the political scandals involving the president of Harvard. [Note: I am not going to discus the politics of this; this is something you can read more on.]  In the case of Harvard, there is famously a movement that their Extension school students feel like second-class citizens because of how Harvard awards the degrees in the field of "Extension Studies" no matter what you study.  I do not believe this is true at similar schools, e.g., Boston University's Metropolitan College.  It very much depends on how the "night school" is viewed within its own community.  The democratic nature of the Harvard Extension School puts it very much at odds with the Ivy League and exclusive nature of Harvard University, hence the HLS professor's comments:

“On Rufo: what do integrity police say about his claim to have ‘master’s degree from Harvard,’ which is actually from the open-enrollment Extension School?” Hochschild wrote on Jan. 4. “Those students are great — I teach them — but they are not the same as what we normally think of as Harvard graduate students.”

In the end, I know that people respect the work I do in my job, and I am constantly upskilling to do better work.  The degrees I get are to perform better work for my job, not to impress other people. When people want to talk to me about my work, it's not interesting to anyone that I may have three master's degrees--it's interesting that I can put together a work product that they love.  They don't care how I learned these things.  The unfortunate reality in academia is that my staff makes more with an undergrad degree than most of the postdocs in our fancy R1 school.  Work experience matters more than education for most jobs (outside of academic pursuits).  When I hire staff (who will be providing customer service to research faculty), I value flexibility, optimism, problem-solving, reliability, and communication skills.  We recently hired someone out of the hospitality industry, and she is a high performer for these reasons.
I also should note that I tend to "stay in my lane" on academia in general.  I am very educated, went to great schools, but I have a sense of where I am educated and where I am not.  I am working on a degree focused on instructional design; that is not the same as a computer science degree, not an education degree.  It has a particular, applied purpose for my job, with elements from computer science programs and elements from education programs.  I am not going to pretend that I know computer science because I took a class from an industry guy at night school on how to make a basic SQL database.  However, in my day to day work, can I deploy a basic SQL database if it solves a problem for me?  Yes, and I am widely-respected in my field for my wide range of skills, not because I am a PhD in a given discipline.  Next week I am starting my first class in GIS--how many people do you know who get to learn these types of skills on the side?  If people look down on me for this, I can't imagine why, and it doesn't matter to me.  My life is so much better for my "less prestigious" education.

Many universities, large and small, have evening programs tailored to the needs of employed people earning masters degrees. I once taught in a doctoral level (computing) program that met face to face only periodically and was meant for part time study by people wishing to move up in their research organizations. This was made possible in part by modern communication systems.
Many people, especially those with families, can't afford to study full time and such programs meet a real need and are quite common.
Many universities try to fill local needs for educational programs. Night and weekend programs make this possible. And some (many?) employers value the fact that employees are working to advance their skills.
Moreover, as I noted in a comment to another answer, it can give faculty at non-research institutions a chance to go beyond the undergraduate program; an important element in keeping current in the field - any field, perhaps. They might be seen as a "carrot" offered to faculty to make academic life more interesting.

(originally a comment, but I decided it probably rises to the level of an answer.)
In the U.S. this is very common in some degree programs, such as MBA programs (Masters in Business Administration), Masters in Nursing programs, Departments of Education (both Masters and EdD (Doctor of Education)), and many other graduate level professional programs. This is especially prevalent in smaller universities (e.g. regional campuses of State Schools) located in more populated areas, such as in cities with population over 100,000.

I don't think it is restricted to a few fields as you may be suggesting.

@Buffy: I agree. I think in my comment (later pasted into an answer window) I was too cautious and was mainly trying to indicate that existence (even nontrivial existence) is definitely the case. Probably the vast majority of Masters programs in the U.S. in most every field have part-time students, although I'm a bit out-of-date with the current situation regarding Ph.D. programs. FYI, the university where I obtained both my undergraduate and Masters degrees offered, in the late 1970s through the 1980s, MA/MS degrees in math with graduate course offerings only in the evenings.

Yes, among other things, it gives faculty at non-research institutions a chance to go beyond the undergrad program; an important element in keeping current.

Although many Universities in the UK may offer part-time studies in various programs, one should mention the University set up here where their entire offering is part-time degrees. This is the Open University which was specifically set up by the government for the purposes you outlined.
You can read about its history on Wikipedia. There are many other similar institutions world-wide which are also listed.

Not only is OU part time, it is also focused on distance education. It does an excellent job in my experience. Among other things it has access to all (most?) of the media produced by the BBC and spends millions on development of new courses.

And to directly address the OP's original question: the OU is well-respected both inside (UK) academia and in wider society. An OU degree is probably better-regarded than one from many of the newer bricks-and-mortar institutions.
